# How should get back the tree view and the object on PgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Hi Im facing a problem on PgAdmin 4. Tree view automatically dissapears and its not poping out, even I can't select any options on ribbon tab. Please help me solving this problem.

I reinstalled it properly I did that twice, even I deleted application file from programme files. [My screen looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8fHI.png)

Comment: file --> reset layout?